# resignFirstResponder within child UIViewController

Tags: swift

I am adding several view controllers to the main view controller by doing

```
addChildViewController(viewController)
viewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

Everything works fine, the only problem is that within my methods for the UITextFieldDelegate, the `resignFirstResponder()` and `becomeFirstResponder()` do not work. If I do `sender.resignFirstResponder()` in an `@IBAction` for example, the function executes, but I can't dismiss the keyboard. Any ideas?

EDIT:
`self.view.endEditing(true)` also doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this, this will work for you:

```
self.view.endEditing(true)
```

OR add this in viewDidAppear:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
```